# Do plum trees fruit if an offspring of another one?

Tags: trees, plums

Can plum trees bare fruit if they arise from the rootstock of another plum tree?

Answer (score 5):

Yes, but the fruit might not be the best.

Plums that bear tasty fruit are usually grafted into a different variety rootstock that is selected for having better root vigor and/or resistance to soil pathogens that the desired fruiting tree may lack. Peach is also used for a plum rootstock sometimes.

It is unlikely that a 'flowering' variety that cannot bear fruit was selected for a rootstock - such trees would be quite valuable for landscape uses. So (otherwise) yes, a root cutting from a plum tree could be grown into a fruit bearing tree.